# Taking the email body information from an Email-To-Case

Tags: email, email2case, parsing

We are currently using Email to Case for one of our customers and they send us in their data straight out of their system i am guessing using a template,

They have the data in the same format and i would like to take the information out of the email body. Below is an example of what we would recieve:

**

Caller: JULIE HOLMES - 
Site: PRIVATE 
Tel: 01633 888310

View call (870896) (requires network and login access) 
View progress of this call (requires network access)

**Your Call Details**

Patient Name

Full Address (inc post code)

Telephone Number

Cytotoxic or Dialysis

Type of Waste (sharps/bags) ie Sharps x 1

Replacement Required ie Yes 1 x 5 litre

Special Notes/Access Issues

Collection Date ie dd/mm/yy

**Answers**

JULIE HOLMES

15 BLACK HALL UNDY NEWPORT NP26 3DW

01633 888310

NO

SHARPS X 1

NO

WILL BE LEFT IN PORCH

30/06/17

-END-

I would like to take all the Answers information an populate salesforce fields with this data. They will always be on the same line,

Any ideas? I have googled and found things like email parsing and Email Service Class but cannot find any step by step guide of how to work this,

Any help would be appreciated,

Kind Regards

matt